# Cookie from ios webview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multithreading

I wanted to ask some things about a piece of code i'm trying to make without having any previous contact with ios or objective-c. 
This piece of code will:

1. Open a WebView with a specific url where the user will login
   (done)
2. After the user logs in it will take the cookie created
   from that login.
3. It will use that cookie in a next request to
   load another site that requires authentication.

I'm stuck a bit at part 2 because it has to a) wait in another thread till the user does the login (how?) and b) because i can't seem to get the specific cookie for the site easily. I have only found and tried this poc but how do I filter out only the cookie for the site I want?

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for(cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

Any ideas on how to make the 2a/b parts? Objective-c syntax seems a bit confusing.

Comment: Hello cyph3r, I am completely new in iOS but still bound to do the same operation as you are doing. App will load on webview, user will login to it and a token will arrive in coockies. I have to get tjat coockies. I really need the workflow and codesnippet of your that how you keep the thread and solved the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution by following this https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-7/embedding-a-web-browser-in-your .
Used the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate and got the cookies from there with the cookiesForURL method.

```
NSArray* availableCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MYURL"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are created as follows,

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          url, NSHTTPCookieOriginURL,
                          @"testCookies", NSHTTPCookieName,
                          @"1", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                          nil];


NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
```

You can use the cookie object to get the origin URL attribute and filter.

```
NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [cookie properties];
NSURL *originURL = [cookieProperties   objectForKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
```

After filtering the cookie you need you can get the cookie value using,

```
cookie.value
```

Comment: But I know the origin url. I just want the data of the cookie that was created after the login in that url. It's basically a session id.

Comment: Ok,Updated the answer. NSHttpCookie class lots of properties. You might want to look at the reference

Comment: You can do that. But I will prefer starting your thread after the user logged in. You can post a notification or use delegate mechanism to inform about the event.

Comment: Ok, i checked the delegate mechanism and it sounds more like what i need. I searched for instructions about the webviewdidfinishload delegate but can't seem easy steps to implement it. Could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Do you need an example to show uiwebview delegates in action?.